# Undo "marked as spam" on Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook-messenger, spam

I was texting with my friend, but I didn't lock my keyboard. I marked her as spam. Do you know how I can get back notifications from her messages?

Comment: How did you manage to 'mark her as spam'? As far as I can see there isn't an option in the Facebook Messenger app to do that nor is there one in the Facebook app's messaging bit. EDIT: Do you mean you just turned off notifications for her messages?

Comment: on my telephone htc evo 3d when i open conversation and i click on 4 lines next to house button (http://www.fony.sk/obr/htc/htc_evo_3d/pic03.jpg) it opens "window" and there is option mark as spam but now it is going. thank you for the assistance

Comment: Odd, I have the same '4 lines', the options button. When I click it on a conversation the options I get are Settings, Logout, About, Archive and Delete. Were you using the main Facebook app or the separate Facebook Messenger app?

Comment: Based from [an edit suggestion by Harry Jackson](http://android.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/90620) "If you mean marked as spam, then you have put them somewhere that you can't see them or read old messages, but there is one way you can get this back: on the message app, type the name of the person that you want to unmark as spam and send them a message. This will then unmark them"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by 'marked as spam' since I can't see this option in either the Facebook app or the Facebook Messenger app. I'm assuming you mean you turned off notifications for her messages since you mention you want to get them back. I'll explain how to turn them back on.

**Facebook Messenger**

- Open up the conversation with person
- Press the 'i' in the circle in the top right 
  [image]
- Click on `Notications` and set to 'On'.

**Facebook App**

- Go to your messages and open up the conversation with the person.
- Click on the gear icon in the top right 
  [image]
- In the `Settings` tab make sure 'Alerts On' is selected.